# web service utf8 arabic decoding

Tags: c#, web-services, unicode, utf-8

I built a c# web service that accepts unicode characters
I have a client that consumes this web service from php to insert data to MS SQL database 
It runs correctly with english characters but when he push arabic text it insert "???????" chars to the database

I tried to decode utf8 to unicode with no luck

here is my conversion code:

```
private byte[] GetRawBytes(string str)
{
    int charcount = str.Length;
    byte[] byttemp = new byte[charcount];
    for (int i = 0; i < charcount; i++)
    {
        byttemp[i] = (byte)str[i];
    }
    return byttemp;
}

private string UTF8toUnicode(string str)
{
    byte[] bytUTF8;
    byte[] bytUnicode;
    string strUnicode = String.Empty;
    bytUTF8 = GetRawBytes(str);
    bytUnicode = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, bytUTF8);
    strUnicode = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytUnicode);
    return strUnicode;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP?

Comment: UTF-8 *is* unicode. Maybe your database column does not support it?

Comment: What's the DB column type?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a method of your own instead of  `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes?`

Comment: Also, it is worth noticing that C# `string`s internally use 2-byte UTF-16 characters. `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16.

Comment: i tagged with PHP because the client is using php to consume my service

Comment: DB column type is nvarchar

Comment: i tried the default and still giving me ????

Comment: can you provide us the starting lines of your wsdl file?

Comment: <wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://asiasat.tv/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://asiasat.tv/">

Comment: What's your database table's character encoding?

Comment: PHP is pretty much completely oblivious to Unicode. So (1) figure out if the text the client is sending is encoded properly (the client could just be sending "????" in the first place). And (2), are you sure the string fed into your `GetRawBytes` function is actually supposed to be encoded as UTF-8? Because in that case, a `byte[]` type argument would make more sense than a `string`.